# Is it possible to detect whether the user entered their Touch ID before entering my app

Tags: ios, touch-id

I have an app that authenticates using Apple's Touch ID which prompts on app coming to foreground. Here is the use case I want to simplify:

User unlocks their phone with Touch ID with my app already in foreground. Then my app also prompts for Touch ID.

I would like my app to not ask for Touch ID if the user had just entered it a few moments earlier. Is it possible to detect this?

Answer (score 1):

*Is it possible to detect whether the user entered their Touch ID before entering my app?*  - NO. There is no API available to communicate to the device passcode screen.

It is possible in the other way. You have to check your login status in your AppDelegate. Store the time when you first login into your app. Compare this time to the time your app has come to foreground/ your app is opened. If the time difference is too large, prompt the touch ID alert.